# Toshiba Chromebook, Freya 0.3.1, Kernel 4.2 - trying to get automatic sleep working

Tags: release-freya, chromebook

I've slowly been working on a Toshiba Chromebook on Freya with the modified SeaBios that allows legacy boot.

Everything (since kernel update) has been working very well. Though I cannot seem to get it to automatically sleep. I've set it to sleep when not used for 10 minutes while on battery and every time I check it has not went to sleep even though when I unlock there is a notification in the top left corner warning **will go to sleep soon**. That sleep/suspend part never happens.

Good news, I can manually suspend and it works like a charm.

This is my first time digging through an issue like this. Any tips on where to look would be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: elementary OS freya was never made for that hardware so expect problems